# How to add an iframe to Wordpress sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the default TwentyEleven theme, and I added the following code to sidebar.php, but it does not work (I get a 310 error)

```
<iframe src="frame.html" name="test" height="600" width="180"></iframe>
```

iframe.html is located in /themes/twentyeleven folder, so it should be working (at least on a regular website).

Is it necessary to use some kind of widget plugin in order to get it to work. What can be preventing the iframe from showing up on the website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hit the file via an http request, not via the local path.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo ( get_site_url() . '/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/iframe.html' ); ?>" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You Should use get_bloginfo('template_directory') before giving path.......
try using 
{

```
<iframe src="<?php echo get_theme_root(); ?>/frame.html" name="test" height="600" width="180"></iframe>
```

}

Try reading this
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_root

Comment: I GET SOMETHING LIKE THIS (STILL THE SAME ERROR) The webpage at http://domain-name.com/home/my-username/public_html/wp-content/themes/frame.html has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: I get the same error (310) when the path is correct, so this dont seem to be the case. THIS IS FROM FIREFOX: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.